# Show $8 ^ \sqrt3\in\Bbb R$, and $(-8)^\sqrt3\not\in\Bbb R$

Tags: complex-numbers, exponentiation

Show that $8 ^ \sqrt3\in\Bbb R$, and $(-8)^\sqrt3\not\in\Bbb R$.

Comment: V3 = root of 3 ..

Comment: You could take natural log of each and manipulate them, then show that the exponential of the second has an imaginary part

Comment: Any idea? ._. ll

Comment: What's $(-8)^{\sqrt 3}$?

Comment: Haha.  ... complex

Comment: I did not understand how to log

Comment: It's not a matter of belonging if it cannot even be defined.. You can ask if something belongs to a set if that something is well-defined.

Comment: Welcome to math.stackexchange. You will find your experience much more valuable if rather than just copying the question you have (making it sound as if you are assigning *us* homework), you provide (i) **context**: where did you encounter this problem? What background has been covered in the course/textbook/article, or that you have, related to the problem? That will help people answering provide you with an answer at the appropriate level that uses appropriate tools; and (ii) **show your effort/work**: what have you done, tried, or where are you stuck? That will help answers be relevant.

Comment: It's a matter of definition. For $a \in \mathbb{R}, a\lt0$, the power $a^r$ is defined only if $r$ is a rational with odd denominator.

Comment: I study alone.  They created this question in an Indian group on the Telegram, and I could not solve it

Comment: (2i²) √3
 2 √3 * (-1) √3
 2 ^ √3 * cis (√3pi) where the imaginary part will not zero

Answer (score 0, accepted):

x^y = exp(y*ln(x))

(-8)^(sqrt3) = exp((sqrt3)*ln(-8))

ln(-8) is not in real, hence exp((sqrt3)*ln(-8)) is also not in real.

Comment: $\frac{2i\pi}{\sqrt 3}$ is not real, hence $1$ is not real. I don't know about you, but this sounds perfectly fine to me.

Comment: I think I got it